# PHP - set canvas.js graph value from input

Tags: php

Im trying to build graph using canvas.js in php, and i want set the graph value from input array.

this my inputed script :

```
echo "<span style='font-size:9pt'><b>Type the data in form bellow and seprate each data with enter.</b><br></span>
<br>";
echo"<form action='' method='post'>
<textarea name='figures' rows='15'></textarea>
<br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='SUBMIT DATA'><br /><input type='reset' name='reset' value='RESET FORM'>
</form>";
```

then set array value using explode:

```
$figures = trim($_POST['figures']);
$data = explode("\n", $figures);
```

i want set array value to this script:

```
$dataPoints1 = array(
    array("y" => value_from_array[0], "label" => "Data 1"),
    array("y" => value_from_array[1], "label" => "Data 2"),
    array("y" => value_from_array[2], "label" => "Data 3"),
    array("y" => value_from_array[3], "label" => "Data 4"),
    //loop get y and x value till last array 
    );
```

I expecting `for` or `while` function or something like that, are anyone can help me?! thanks.

Comment: And why do you want to do it via PHP? Waste of resources. You can do it client side.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a for loop and `array_push`

```
$dataPoints1 = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) - 1; $i++){
    array_push($dataPoints1,
       array("y" => $data[$i], "label" => "Data " . $i + 1));
}
```

The `array_push` function appends the new value to the target array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: The value on graph is not showing up, but no error displayed. are there any mistake?

Comment: Not in my code.  You'll have to debug the values returned to make sure they match what you want